# input date y hora

Tags: php, javascript, html, datetime

Tengo un input en el que selecciono la fecha y un select para marcar la hora.

De esos dos input, tengo que hacer un insert a la base de datos ya que el campo es datetime.

**Como podría hacerlo?**

No puedo usar datatimepicker, porque me desconfigura la app, y no logro hacer que la base de datos me guarde bien los datos.

**El html es el siguiente:**

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">
    <label for="exampleInputName4" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Ingreso</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="border: 0px solid; padding-right: 0px;" >
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechahoraA" onchange="horaAsignadaA(this.selectedIndex)"  value="<?php echo $fecha;?>"  <?php echo ($usuario->rol_id ==1||$usuario->rol_id ==6)?'':' disabled '; ?>>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="border: 0px solid; padding-left: 0px;">
        <select class="form-control" id="horaingresoA">
            <option value='00:00' id='fechahoraA00:00'>00:00</option>
            <option value='00:30' id='fechahoraA00:30'>00:30</option>
            <option value='01:00' id='fechahoraA01:00'>01:00</option>
            <option value='01:30' id='fechahoraA01:30'>01:30</option>
            <option value='02:00' id='fechahoraA02:00'>02:00</option>
            <option value='02:30' id='fechahoraA02:30'>02:30</option>
            <option value='03:00' id='fechahoraA03:00'>03:00</option>
            <option value='03:30' id='fechahoraA03:30'>03:30</option>
            <option value='04:00' id='fechahoraA04:00'>04:00</option>
            <option value='04:30' id='fechahoraA04:30'>04:30</option>
            <option value='05:00' id='fechahoraA05:00'>05:00</option>
            <option value='05:30' id='fechahoraA05:30'>05:30</option>
            <option value='06:00' id='fechahoraA06:00'>06:00</option>
            <option value='06:30' id='fechahoraA06:30'>06:30</option>
            <option value='07:00' id='fechahoraA07:00'>07:00</option>
            <option value='07:30' id='fechahoraA07:30'>07:30</option>
            <option value='08:00' id='fechahoraA08:00'>08:00</option>
            <option value='08:30' id='fechahoraA08:30'>08:30</option>
            <option value='09:00' id='fechahoraA09:00'>09:00</option>
            <option value='09:30' id='fechahoraA09:30'>09:30</option>
            <option value='10:00' id='fechahoraA10:00'>10:00</option>
            <option value='10:30' id='fechahoraA10:30'>10:30</option>
            <option value='11:00' id='fechahoraA11:00'>11:00</option>
            <option value='11:30' id='fechahoraA11:30'>11:30</option>
            <option value='12:00' id='fechahoraA12:00'>12:00</option>
            <option value='12:30' id='fechahoraA12:30'>12:30</option>
            <option value='13:00' id='fechahoraA13:00'>13:00</option>
            <option value='13:30' id='fechahoraA13:30'>13:30</option>
            <option value='14:00' id='fechahoraA14:00'>14:00</option>
            <option value='14:30' id='fechahoraA14:30'>14:30</option>
            <option value='15:00' id='fechahoraA15:00'>15:00</option>
            <option value='15:30' id='fechahoraA15:30'>15:30</option>
            <option value='16:00' id='fechahoraA16:00'>16:00</option>
            <option value='16:30' id='fechahoraA16:30'>16:30</option>
            <option value='17:00' id='fechahoraA17:00'>17:00</option>
            <option value='17:30' id='fechahoraA17:30'>17:30</option>
            <option value='18:00' id='fechahoraA18:00'>18:00</option>
            <option value='18:30' id='fechahoraA18:30'>18:30</option>
            <option value='19:00' id='fechahoraA19:00'>19:00</option>
            <option value='19:30' id='fechahoraA19:30'>19:30</option>
            <option value='20:00' id='fechahoraA20:00'>20:00</option>
            <option value='20:30' id='fechahoraA20:30'>20:30</option>
            <option value='21:00' id='fechahoraA21:00'>21:00</option>
            <option value='21:30' id='fechahoraA21:30'>21:30</option>
            <option value='22:00' id='fechahoraA22:00'>22:00</option>
            <option value='22:30' id='fechahoraA22:30'>22:30</option>
            <option value='23:00' id='fechahoraA23:00'>23:00</option>
            <option value='23:30' id='fechahoraA23:30'>23:30</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

Answer (score 1):

Pues es bastante simple. Puedes o bien, unir las fechas por javascript o por php antes de hacer el insert a la base de datos.

PHP

```
$fechahoraA= $_POST['fechahoraA'];
$horaingresoA = $_POST['horaingresoA'];
$dateTimeInsertar = $fechahoraA.' '.$horaingresoA.':00';
```

Recuerda que date time es YYYY-MM-DD

Y si el usuario esta mandando DD-MM-YYYY, te dará error lógicamente.

Espeor haberte podido ayudar. Éxito en tu proyecto